# Volume of revolution

Tags: cinema4d

How can I generate a volume of revolution of the following plane around the point (bottom left)?

[image]

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Select the edges and revolve those. (PS there si no such things as true volumes that consist out of polygons in cinema or in fact most applications, they fool you with closed boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Lathe object but first you have to convert your mesh to a spline. Select the perimeter edges of your mesh and then go to Mesh->Conversion-> Mesh to Spline.